# Is it possible to Sum this data with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Is it possible to Sum this data with XSLT? I have the following dataset

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <recordType>EXP</recordType>
      <AppContribAmt>0.0</AppContribAmt>
      <LdgCost>658.82</LdgCost>
      <LabCostIn>0.0</LabCostIn>
      <LabCostOut>0.0</LabCostOut>
      <ServiceCost>0.0</ServiceCost>
      <MatCostIn>0.0</MatCostIn>
      <MatCostOut>0.0</MatCostOut>
      <ToolCostIn>0.0</ToolCostIn>
      <ToolCostOut>0.0</ToolCostOut>
      <recordType>ADD</recordType>
      <AppContribAmt>0.0</AppContribAmt>
      <LdgCost>932.5</LdgCost>
      <LabCostIn>104.64</LabCostIn>
      <LabCostOut>0.0</LabCostOut>
      <ServiceCost>0.0</ServiceCost>
      <MatCostIn>260.36</MatCostIn>
      <MatCostOut>0.0</MatCostOut>
      <ToolCostIn>0.0</ToolCostIn>
      <ToolCostOut>0.0</ToolCostOut>
      <recordType>ADD</recordType>
      <AppContribAmt>0.0</AppContribAmt>
      <LdgCost>932.5</LdgCost>
      <LabCostIn>104.64</LabCostIn>
      <LabCostOut>0.0</LabCostOut>
      <ServiceCost>0.0</ServiceCost>
      <MatCostIn>260.36</MatCostIn>
      <MatCostOut>0.0</MatCostOut>
      <ToolCostIn>0.0</ToolCostIn>
      <ToolCostOut>0.0</ToolCostOut>
      <recordType>ADD</recordType>
      <AppContribAmt>0.0</AppContribAmt>
      <LdgCost>932.5</LdgCost>
      <LabCostIn>104.64</LabCostIn>
      <LabCostOut>0.0</LabCostOut>
      <ServiceCost>0.0</ServiceCost>
      <MatCostIn>260.36</MatCostIn>
      <MatCostOut>0.0</MatCostOut>
      <ToolCostIn>0.0</ToolCostIn>
      <ToolCostOut>0.0</ToolCostOut>
      <recordType>EXP</recordType>
      <AppContribAmt>0.0</AppContribAmt>
      <LdgCost>0.0</LdgCost>
      <LabCostIn>322.95</LabCostIn>
      <LabCostOut>0.0</LabCostOut>
      <ServiceCost>0.0</ServiceCost>
      <MatCostIn>0.0</MatCostIn>
      <MatCostOut>0.0</MatCostOut>
      <ToolCostIn>0.0</ToolCostIn>
      <ToolCostOut>0.0</ToolCostOut>
</data>
```

I am trying to sum the values under recordType='EXP' to one total and the values under recordType='ADD' to another total. Is this possible or do I need to change the XML format to something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <recordType value='EXP'>
      <AppContribAmt>0.0</AppContribAmt>
      <LdgCost>658.82</LdgCost>
      <LabCostIn>0.0</LabCostIn>
      <LabCostOut>0.0</LabCostOut>
      <ServiceCost>0.0</ServiceCost>
      <MatCostIn>0.0</MatCostIn>
      <MatCostOut>0.0</MatCostOut>
      <ToolCostIn>0.0</ToolCostIn>
      <ToolCostOut>0.0</ToolCostOut>
</recordType>
<recordType value='ADD'>
      <AppContribAmt>0.0</AppContribAmt>
      <LdgCost>932.5</LdgCost>
      <LabCostIn>104.64</LabCostIn>
      <LabCostOut>0.0</LabCostOut>
      <ServiceCost>0.0</ServiceCost>
      <MatCostIn>260.36</MatCostIn>
      <MatCostOut>0.0</MatCostOut>
      <ToolCostIn>0.0</ToolCostIn>
      <ToolCostOut>0.0</ToolCostOut>
</recordType>
</data>
```

Comment: If you have control over the XML, I would definitely suggest changing it to something like your second example. It's not absolutely necessary though. You can use muenchian grouping to get the sums. (I will check back later when I'm not on my phone to see if anyone has added an answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another XSLT 1.0 option that is a little bit more complicated, but should be* much more efficient if you have a larger data set.

*I tested with Saxon-HE 9.6 and duplicated your data so the file was 10,353 lines and this stylesheet ran in about 150ms compared to about 1500ms with the other answer (based on the output of the "-t" switch). Results may vary with actual data and different processors, so you might want to test.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="recordTypes" match="recordType" use="."/>
  <xsl:key name="byRecordType" match="*[not(self::recordType)]" 
    use="preceding-sibling::recordType[1]"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <results>
      <xsl:for-each select="recordType[count(.|key('recordTypes',.)[1])=1]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="recordType">
    <sum type="{.}">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('byRecordType',.))"/>
    </sum>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<results>
   <sum type="EXP">981.77</sum>
   <sum type="ADD">3892.5</sum>
</results
```

Comment: Tested in MSXSL, your solution is ~5% slower. Actually, it really depends on the processor. On 26K lines both solutions run in less than 150ms on my laptop :)

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk - Thanks for the info! I figured there would be differences with other processors, that's why I included the "results may vary/do your own testing" disclaimer. Your answer is a good one (as always), just wanted to add an alternative .

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this for the first XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k" match="recordType" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="recordType[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', .))]">
    <total name="{.}">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('k', .)
                    /following-sibling::*[not(self::recordType)][preceding-sibling::recordType[1] = current()])"/>
    </total>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<total name="EXP">981.77</total>
<total name="ADD">3892.5</total>
```